# Count same id column with different condition in same select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, count

I need to combine both select statements into one select

```
SELECT count(tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id) pending
  FROM tbl_employer_post_details, 
       tbl_employer_registration
 WHERE job_status=0 
   AND tbl_employer_registration.employer_id = 
                                   tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id
 LIMIT start,max;
```

And the second query, with the only difference being the `WHERE job_status=1`:

```
SELECT count(tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id) approved
  FROM tbl_employer_post_details, 
       tbl_employer_registration
 WHERE job_status=1 
   AND tbl_employer_registration.employer_id = 
                         tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id
  LIMIT start,max;
```

Comment: Do you want the counts combined (eg, 5 total employees, of either status), or separated (2 with job status 0, 3 with job status 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(job_status = 0) pending, SUM(job_status = 1) approved 
FROM tbl_employer_post_details epd 
INNER JOIN tbl_employer_registration er ON epd.employer_id = er.employer_id
WHERE job_status IN (0, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way

```
SELECT SUM(job_status = 0) pending,
       SUM(job_status = 1) approved
  FROM tbl_employer_post_details d JOIN tbl_employer_registration r
    ON r.employer_id = d.employer_id
 WHERE job_status IN (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id) PostDetails
FROM tbl_employer_post_details, tbl_employer_registration
WHERE job_status IN(0,1) AND  
tbl_employer_registration.employer_id=tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id LIMIT start,max;

SELECT SUM(job_status = 0) pending,
       SUM(job_status = 1) approved
FROM tbl_employer_post_details, tbl_employer_registration
WHERE job_status IN(0,1) AND  
tbl_employer_registration.employer_id=tbl_employer_post_details.employer_id LIMIT start,max;
```

Comment: I think he wants 2 columns returned?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
  SELECT SUM(case when job_status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) pending,
         SUM(case when job_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) approved
  FROM tbl_employer_post_details d JOIN tbl_employer_registration r
    ON r.employer_id = d.employer_id
 WHERE job_status IN (0, 1)
```